# In React Native (with NativeBase), why am I getting an error message 'expected a string...'

Tags: react-native, native

My Snack is here:

https://snack.expo.io/@mary21/spunky-pastry

I am copying the sample code from here:

http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-input-headref

I am receiving the following error message:

> Device: (101:380) Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: What is the version of nativeBase installed?

Comment: It's Native Base 2.8.1